# How to use linux split command on the file in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a big file in HDFS and want to split it into multiple chunks.

If the file is in my local file system, I can use split to achieve it.

However, the file is in HDFS and I don't want (can't) copy it into the local file system.

How can I directly use **split** command on the file in HDFS?

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: *I have a big file in HDFS and want to split it into multiple chunks*. That makes no sense. HDFS already splits the file within your cluster

Comment: @cricket_007 It surely makes sense. HDFS splits the files internally and does not expose it to you.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean that you can't go into the physical hdfs directory on each datanode and inspect some subset of the input file

Comment: MapReduce does not copy to a single node. It works on a single input split. Only if your data is not splittable (such as a gzip file), then will a single mapper process it. For what it's worth, Apache Spark is easier to work on than pure MapReduce

Comment: is your data structured or have table structured fields or it is pure unstructured data like images?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of HDFS and Unix commands can do the job if the file size is not significantly large.

However, I would not recommend it. The Hadoop framework will split the file into smaller chunks (default size is 64MB for Hadoop-1.X & 128MB for Hadoop-2.X) and physically distributed across the cluster.

Can you describe the reason for splitting the file on HDFS?

Comment: The file size is over a few TB which exceeds capacity of a single disk. 
I need to copy the contents of a file in HDFS to the local file system of multiple machines. To do that, I first need split the file in HDFS explicitly.
(I don't know how to write Map/Reduce program, I just use HDFS as a distributed file system.)

Comment: Have you tried compression utility like bzip2 which is also splittable in HDFS?